# Using Excel Chart Elements in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-excel-2003

How do I make Excel chart pie slices available for custom animation along with other elements in a PowerPoint slide?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for in this?  You want to make a pie chart from excel and import it and then animate that?

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  Make graph in Excel.  Paste as object in ppt.  Then the key step is to ungroup all the objects within the graph.  Once you do that, you can group them with the other things on the slide that you want to animate with the individual pie slices.  If you don't ungroup everything, you can't group what you want.  That was my problem.

Comment: You should probably post your answer as an answer and then select it, to close out the question

Answer (score 1):

Re-create the chart in PowerPoint directly. There are layouts for charts. In 2003, it takes you to a sub program called MS Graph. It is very close to Excel's charting feature and works in similar ways. Copy the data that produced your chart in Excel and paste it into the datasheet PowerPoint provides. Then just create the same chart. You'll be able to animate the pie then.

After you apply an animation to your chart it will apply to the chart as a whole. If you want to animate individual pieces (e.g. pie wedges) then select the animation you applied in the animation pane. There will be a drop-down arrow and you want to select "Effect Options". Go to the "Chart Animation" tab and you'll see your drop down options for applying the animation to pieces at a time.

Note -- In 2003, not all animations support cutting up the chart. If you go to that drop-down and all it says is "as one object", it means that particular animation doesn't support cutting up the chart. Delete that animation and try another.